# jquerymobile listview events - number of remaining items after filter applied

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to find an easy way to check how many list items are left after a list has been filtered.

I can pick up when the list is being filtered via

```
$("#theList").listview('option', 'filterCallback', function( text, searchValue )         {

         //how many list items are there??
         return text.toLowerCase().indexOf( searchValue ) === -1;
     });
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I'm really looking to hook onto a filter applied event if possible.
Not having much luck with the docs so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To count the remaining li showing, use the psudo-selector of ":visible" like this...

$("#theList li:visible").length

Comment: this works but the event doesn't bubble and the filter doesn't actually happen. but I am able to capture the event.  Thoughts?

Comment: The way I've always done it was to hook into the keyup event.  Inside that I did the length count on the visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check for the presence of class `ui-screen-hidden`:

```
$('#theList li').length - $('#theList .ui-screen-hidden').length
```