# how to find the count of visible list items in search filter jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile

I have implemented a phone gap app for android using jQuery Mobile and java script.

in my app

I have added a **list view** dynamically and used **search filter** attribute (true).

Now i want to popup an alert for every search.

That alert sh'd shows the **count of the visible list** items for entering of every character.

how?

Thnaks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following should give you the count of currently visible `li`s in a `listview` with `id=myList`

`$('#myList li').size() - $('#myList li.ui-screen-hidden').size()`

http://jsfiddle.net/nirmaljpatel/Vy7Vu/

Comment: it is worth to mention that - "The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call." - http://api.jquery.com/size/

Answer (score 3):

I have made you an example on that does what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/Calavoow/ddTX9/3/

It uses the css selector from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897433/jquerymobile-listview-events-number-of-remaining-items-after-filter-applied) for quick counting of elements.

The javascript code uses a listview with `id="filterlist"`.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function() {
    $("#filterlist").prev().on("keyup",function(){
        count();
    });
});

function count(){
    var elements = $("#filterlist li:visible").length;
    alert(elements);
}
```