# jquery listview how can i get the filter result counter?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery filtered  listView:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
   <li data-filtertext="Hola"><a href="" >Hola</a></li>
   <li data-filtertext="mundo"><a href="" >mundo</a></li>
   <li data-filtertext="hello"><a href="" >hello</a></li>
   <li data-filtertext="world"><a href="" >world</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I do to know how many results return the listview when type **hi** in filter bar ?

I want to show a button when search return no results.

http://jsfiddle.net/jupagose/KwFXN/

Comment: What do you mean by that ?? Can you be a little more clear as this makes no sense..

Comment: I want to know if there is no results when type any text

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquerymobile listview events - number of remaining items after filter applied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897433/jquerymobile-listview-events-number-of-remaining-items-after-filter-applied)

Comment: In other words I want to know when listview filter return 0 matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I have to do is to delegate **keyup** event of the textbox to another function.

This code works for me.

```
var $listview = $('#myListId');
$('#PageId').delegate('input[data-type="search"]', 'keyup', function () {
    if ($listview.children(':visible').length === 0) {
        alert('There is no results for your search');
    }
});
```